# Azure Web App and .NetCore WebAPI - Missing web.config

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service

From what I understand .NetCore no longer uses/needs web.config -- opting instead for appsettings.json.

I have a .NetCore WebAPI that I am trying to host in an Azure WebApp.  I've published the API to the WebApp but I keep getting a 500 error.  Looking in the Application logs, I can see that the error is:

```
IIS was not able to access the web.config file for the web site or application.
```

I'm confused.  If .NetCore uses appsettings.json instead of web.config and Azure won't work without web.config, how is one supposed to host a .NetCore app in Azure?

**UPDATE**

I now realize that this has nothing to do with web.config thanks to @joey-cai pointing me in the right direction.

It appears that Azure did not like my attempt to use Azure Active Directory Authentication in my Connection String.  I changed my connection string to simply use SQL Authentication and everything worked.  So I guess my question now is, how do I use AAD Authentication for my connection string rather than SQL Authentication.

[This SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46681021/can-not-connect-to-azure-sql-server-using-active-directory-integrated-authentica) seems to indicate that my connection string was indeed set up correctly for AAD authentication, but I was getting the error:

```
Keyword not supported: 'authentication'
```

whenever I used the connection string like so:

```
Server=tcp:dbname.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=dbnamesqldb;Persist Security Info=False;User ID={your_username};Password={your_password};MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Authentication="Active Directory Password";
```

Since the question has now changed, [I'm going to create a new post with the new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54518643/keyword-not-supported-authentication-when-using-active-directory-password-aga).

Comment: I think that you're Azure Web App thinks you're running an ASP.NET (.NET Framework) application.    Let me check the documentation and get back to you.

Comment: Not sure of all of your app requirements. See quick start information here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/azure-apps/?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Comment: IIS still uses Web.config and the standard Azure WebApps service uses IIS.

Comment: So what is the minimum that one would need to have in web.config to get IIS working on web app?

Comment: Did you azure web app has hosted in linux or windows OS ?

Comment: Windows OS - does this mean I must have we.config?  If so, can it just be an empty file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> does this mean I must have we.config? If so, can it just be an empty file?

When you deploy the .net core project to Azure, you could go to `https://xxxxx.scm.azurewebsites.net` and click `Debug console> CMD > site > wwwroot > web.config.` The `web.config` will be there.

Try to delete the site in azure and recreat the site in azure. Also, try to run the application that you are deploying by running `dotnet MyApp.dll` and making sure that works. You need more details as to why it’s having an application issue. This might help. Also consider testing using a self contained application. Also try installing the [asp.net core extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/azure-apps/?view=aspnetcore-2.1#deploy-aspnet-core-preview-release-to-azure-app-service) on the azure app service.

For more details, you could refer to [Deploy ASP.NET Core apps to Azure App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/azure-apps/?view=aspnetcore-2.1).

Comment: Running the app like you said `dotnet app.dll` shows me that it is launching but is using my development setting of `localhost:5000`.  I'm not sure where it is pulling that value from -- how do I fix that?

Comment: So looking in my logs, I'm getting the following error: `Keyword not supported: 'authentication'.`  I found [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34943369/azure-active-directory-connection-string) that seems to indicate that .Net Framework 4.6 or later must be installed -- but I don't think I have any control over what is installed with a Web App.  I'm trying to use `Authentication="Active Directory Password"` in my connection string

Comment: Thanks, you were correct that web.config is actually there (even though it is not part of my project).  Don't know why I was seeing that error, but you got me digging in the right places to find the actual error and a partial resolution -- Thanks.