# "Keyword not supported: authentication" when using Active Directory Password against AAD in Azure Web App

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-web-app-service

I'm have an Azure Web App where I've set the connection string to point to an Azure SQL DB.  I'd prefer to use an Azure Active Directory username/password for authentication so I used the following connection string:

```
Server=tcp:mydb.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=mytable;Persist Security Info=False;User ID={your_username};Password={your_password};MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Authentication="Active Directory Password";
```

This causes my app to fail with the error:

```
Keyword not supported: 'authentication'
```

If I use the SQL Authentication (i.e. remove the `Authentication="Active Directory Password"` and change `User ID` and `Password` to an appropriate SQL username and password), everything works as expected.

Is it possible to use `Active Directory Password` with an Azure Web App connection string in order to use an AAD username/password to connect to an Azure SQL Db?

Comment: Were you able to have this fixed?

Answer (score 0):

Please change the connection string as shown below:

```
string ConnectionString =
@"Data Source=n9lxnyuzhv.database.windows.net; Authentication=Active Directory Password; Initial Catalog=testdb;  UID=bob@contoso.onmicrosoft.com; PWD=MyPassWord!";
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
conn.Open();
```

Another option:

```
string ConnectionString =
@"Data Source=n9lxnyuzhv.database.windows.net; Authentication=Active Directory Integrated; Initial Catalog=testdb;";
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
conn.Open();
```

Please note the text following the Authentication keyword.